# Can you bring an adjustable spanner on an airplane from Åland?

Tags: air-travel, airport-security, prohibited-items, aland, air-leap

Apparently I've had an adjustable spanner in my suitcase for who knows how long. On my most recent flight I had to have it tossed away in airport security. This even though I've flown with it many times before. And I only flew on a short domestic flight in a 20 seat airplane.

The reason the officer gave me was "You are not allowed to bring tools on-board".

I find this rather silly. Is it true?

My spanner was the same size as the one pictured below, or maybe even smaller.

[image: A normal adjustable spanner]

Comment: It was Åland, so maybe [the Finnish list](https://www.finnair.com/se/gb/information-services/baggage/dangerous-goods).

Comment: Same thing happened on Malaysia - KLIA2. it was a really small normal spanner.

Comment: (If you are a bad guy,) you could use it to disassemble critical pieces of the airplane during flight, which they obviously wouldn't appreciate.

Comment: @Aganju wouldn't I just bring a [credit card shaped carbon fiber spanner](https://imgur.com/DLRVh3V) if I was a bad guy?

Comment: I brought a digital voltmeter on board once.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica how did you conceal it?

Comment: @MikaelDúiBolinder I disguised it as a digital ammeter.

Comment: @MikaelDúiBolinder , the restrictions are not supposed to help against terrorists, but give the public a feeling of security. All the limits are easily bypassed for anyone with a brain (fortunately, many terrorists are not in that class).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Finnair](https://www.finnair.com/se/gb/information-services/baggage/dangerous-goods) links to the website of security consultancy firm [Finsecpro](http://www.mitamukaanlennolle.fi/en) which has a searchable database of "What to bring on a flight".  If you search for [adjustable wrench](http://www.mitamukaanlennolle.fi/en/objects/detail/adjustable-wrench), it says "Cabin baggage: No."

So if this is accurate, the officer was correct to tell you that you cannot bring your spanner on board.